# Does my website require https/ssl for Paypal Express Checkout for recurring payment?

Tags: paypal

I am not sure it is neccessary if I am using PayPal express checkout for recurring payment, do I need https/ssl for my website to connect to PayPal? I am using Ruby on Rails and there is a gem called "paypal-express". It is working well without ssl in sandbox environment. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by 'https/ssl' you mean whether your site itself needs to support SSL traffic over HTTP (and thus have a valid SSL certificate): no, it doesn't.

You **do** however need to be able to establish an SSL connection. Specifically, to PayPal's API endpoint.
This means you need to allow outbound SSL traffic via your firewall (if you have any) and your environment needs to support this.

Ensure you have a valid copy of the root certs (I usually suggest http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) to valid the SSL certificates against.

Comment: Thank you. I wish to make this clear, so my website still requires a ssl cert to establish a connection to PayPal endpoint, even though it is not required in the sandbox environment.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You need to be able to establish an SSL connection to PayPal's API endpoint, but you do not need an SSL certificate yourself.

Comment: Is this policy changed in 2014?

Comment: It hasn't, no. However, if you're collecting personal data on your website it's still of course highly recommended to offer your site over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks required SSL as stated here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/